Why is my mediaInfo command not accepting template?
MediaInfo v24.06 (latest at the time of writing) does not accept my template.txt. I've been trying with:
MediaInfo.exe --output=file://template.txt "videofile.mp4"

The file is confirmed to work with MediaInfo, in fact every time I try to use the template file it just prints output in a regular manner, as if I entered mediainfo videofile.mp4, and according to the printout it appears to be a healthy video file for testing. I have tried using --output=video;file://template.txt and full path has also been tried.
I started questioning everything like the validity of my parameters, so I printed out the --info-parameters into a text file, transformed them to valid ones by wrapping them all in % and removing the deprecated ones. I still get nothing. I can't even find any documentation about this. ChatGPT can't help either. Now questioning my sanity.
This started with FFmpeg data fetching, then ffprobe, then mediainfo. There is always some severe problems, complexity and inconsistency to data retrieval. I'm looking for a simple, idiot proof way to all this.

You didn't provide the template.txt so difficult to say, but generally speaking this is the way:
PS > get-content .\template.txt
General;%Format%
PS > MediaInfo.exe --output=file://template.txt .\MediaInfo.exe
MZ


To be honest, I struggle the same but then I let mediainfo export everything and then tell jq to filter and then use python to decorate to whatever I want

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
